# Handling German umlauts in Apache Solr

Tags: php, apache, solr

I am new to Apache Solr. I am using the Solr PHP Client for interaction between the Solr and my PHP web application.

The problem im facing is with German umlaut characters. Whenever I try to search a string having umlaut character in it, Solr throws an exception as given below:

```
exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''400' Status: Bad Request' 
in C:\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php:338 
Stack trace: #0 C:\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php(1170): 
Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawGet('http://localhost...') #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\MyProject\results.php(42):
Apache_Solr_Service->search('f?r', 0, 10) #2 {main}
```

***As you can see the German "für" is displayed as "f?r"***

I tried to covert it using iconv() and htmlentities() but these returned false or empty.

This is my code:

```
    $query = "für"; //string with German umlaut

try {
    //instantiate a Solr object
    $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service(SOLRHOST, SOLRPORT, SOLRNAME);

    // Check if Solr is running
    if (!$solr->ping()) {
        echo 'Solr service not responding!';
        exit;
    }

    // I have tried these functions
    // $query = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT",$query);
    // $query = htmlentities($query,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');

    //run the query
    $results = $solr->search($query, 0, 10); // exception occurs here

    $numDocs = $results->response->numFound;
    $docs = $results->response->docs;
    // Check if there are any results
    if (empty($numDocs) || $numDocs <= 0) {
        print_r($docs);
        echo "No records found!!";
    } else {
        echo ("No. of docs:".$numDocs."<br/>");
        print_r($docs);
        echo "records found!!";
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $log->error($e->getMessage());
    echo($e->__toString());
}
```

Comment: Would you please add the full error message? You may have cut off an interesting part after `Bad Request' in C...`

Comment: Hi cheffe, I have update the error message above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting message 400, then there should be a real error message on the Solr's side in the logs. See what that says, it should point you in the right direction.

Also, compare the query generated when you search for your text directly from the Admin UI and when you search from your PHP code. You may be able to see the difference and identify where the failure is.

Comment: Hi Alex, Yes I checked that but the Solr does not display any error. Also, in the Solr admin I tried querying for the same text "für" and I get desired results. I get error only while querying it on php side.

Comment: Are you getting anything at all on Solr's side to indicate you actually got all the way from PHP to Solr? If not, maybe you are hitting something all together different.

If all else fails, you could run something like Wireshark and see what PHP is actually writing down on the wire and compare that to a working request. But you would need to point to a different host from localhost. E.g. example.com. Or use Runscope.com It will come back with an error, but at least you will see the query.